# What is the meta-box-order_post_hash used for?

Tags: user-meta

`meta-box-order_post_hash` is stored as an user option. I am sure it's related to `meta-box-order_post` but I could not find anything in the codex about it. So what is it for? And how can or should be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could only find the following core code references for the `meta-box-order_` string:

```
/wp-admin/includes/ajax-actions.php: 
   update_user_option($user->ID, "meta-box-order_$page", $order, true);
```

and

```
/wp-admin/includes/template.php: 
    ... get_user_option( "meta-box-order_$page" ) ...
```

that's related to the ordering of meta-boxes.

I doubt your `$page` value is `post_hash`, so my first guess is that this comes from a plugin/theme? If not then the user option might be dynamically constructed.

Searching the wide world web gave be only [this](https://github.com/LettoBlog/post-meta-box-order/blob/cdf9f7f9f00eb70bd354bebe09e0be1ac113b5a4/post-meta-box-order.php#L84) plugin on GitHub, that uses the `meta-box-order_post_hash` user meta key.

*Thanks to @toscho for the information about the handy <kbd>y</kbd> key on GitHub, to retrieve [permanent links to GitHub files](https://help.github.com/articles/getting-permanent-links-to-files/) that I didn't use in previous answers ;-)*

Comment: You're right. That's coming from a plugin that was installed a while ago and removed. I guess that's left over data. Thank you!

Comment: I checked my databse just in case and I found no traces of `meta-box-order_post_hash` there. So this tells us why prefixing custom meta keys is important for plugins & themes ;-) @gdaniel